# OIDs expected by NMS to draw the topology

Tags: snmp, switching, snmp4j, opennms

I am writing a SNMP Agent for an Ethernet switch.

The agent is able to run and reply to provide `SysDescr`. It has been written in a modular design, such that, one can add OIDs very easily.

Now, my intention is to create a topology (say ring) of the switches and discover the topology using a common Network Management System like HP-NNMi or OpenNMS (I am testing on OpenNMS btw).

I just want to know, what **oids** are queried by an NMS, to gather enough information to draw the topology?

[EDIT] I can know, what is the MAC of the remote switches connected to any port of a switch, through MAC learning.

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on what type of topology you want to capture through your ethernet switch. Usually for a layer two switch (which appears to be the case) LLDP MIB (This is an IEEE std implemented by many switches) is quite useful. From what you described above that is you have information about MACs on a port it appears you probably can go this route. There are some other Physical topology MIBs (like [RFC2292](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2922)) that you may want to look at.

Answer (score 0):

You can have a look at the [OpenNMS Enhanced Linkd](http://docs.opennms.org/opennms/releases/20.0.2/guide-admin/guide-admin.html#_transparent_bridge_discovery) documentation. It will give you some hints which OID's are used to build a Layer-2 topology based on LLDP, CDP and the Bridge MIB. To build it a topology based on the Bridge MIB, OpenNMS has implemented the algorithm described in [Topology Discovery for Large Ethernet Networks](http://cs-pub.bu.edu/groups/nrg/readinglist/lowekamp-sigcomm01.pdf). You'll find also hints what information is used to build an OSPF and IS-IS topology.

Answer (score 0):

Every NMS uses their proprietary topology discovery.
Depending on what your switch supports, you'll want to consider at least

- RFC1213-MIB ipAddrTable, ipRouteTable
- IF-MIB ifTable
- IP-FORWARD-MIB inetCidrRouteTable
- BRIDGE-MIB dot1dTpFdbTable, dot1dStpPortTable
- Q-BRIDGE-MIB dot1qTpFdbTable
- LLDP-MIB lldpLocPortTable, lldpRemTable
- OSPF-MIB
- BGP4-MIB

and if you support VLANs, you'll want to describe those.
We have seen other MIBs queried by NMS applications.